# How to set 100% height of a nested table while using DOCTYPE tag?

Tags: asp.net

I have a child table inside the cell of parent table. I want to stretch the child table so that i covers full space in the cell of parent table. Also i need to keep the DOCTYPE tag. Please suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

See - [How to set 100% table height in html](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/howtoset100tableheightinhtml.aspx)

This solution will work independent of DOCTYPE

Comment: i need to use DOCTYPE tag in my website.